# Is there an "internal link click" handling logic in Blazor that calls preventDefault when it recognizes clicks on internal links?

Tags: blazor

Suppose I have this element in my component:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="@IncrementCount">Click me</a>
```

When you click the link, instead of incrementing the counter, it jumps to the "#" url, navigating to the home page (Blazor default behavior). My expected behavior, however, is that the counter would be incremented.

Note: I do not ask how to prevent the default action; I rather want to know if an **"internal link click" handling logic** do exist as Steve Sanderson says here: https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/pull/937
And if it does, could you please provide its location.

As far as I know, in Blazor, the only default action that is prevented is the submission of a form (traditional post), but I might be proved wrong ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blazor does call prevent default on anchor tag onclick events, however, only when the location is within the base tags URI space.

The particular piece of code can be viewed [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/98fe8a8328a0b41ac776a1ccdc71943de8093440/src/Components/Browser.JS/src/Services/UriHelper.ts#L22).

In the code example you’ve provided, I would suggest you use a button then you would not have to worry about the navigation event. Anchor element should only be used to navigate, not to perform general actions specifically as it avoids the event issue you’ve found.

Hope this helps.

Comment: by saying that I'm correct you mean that what Steve Anderson says here is not true ? As this was my question, not how to solve this issue, but is there an  “internal link click” handling logic in Blazor that calls preventDefault when it recognizes clicks on internal links, as Steve Anderson says in a github issue. See link above. I can verify it by perusing the code, but have got no time, and thought I may get the answer here. It seems to me that no such logic exists, as I know that the only default action prevented is a form submission. But I want to be sure about it... Thanks...

Comment: I've updated my answer, I've had a chance to check over some code and my initial answer was mistaken. Hopefully, this is the answer you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your response, @Chris Sainty. I'm well acquainted with this code whose role is to prevent the default action of the anchor element, thus enabling internal navigation. This definitely cannot provide me with a way to prevent the default action of the anchor element, and executes code in the  click event handler IncrementCount (see my question). I can either employ JSInterop or wait for 3.0.0-preview6. See this: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/5545